# Is there something wrong in my parallel processing code? How to use multiprocessing.Process and multiprocessing.Queue function?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, process, multiprocessing, queue

I coded for the parallel processing, but it takes long time. I guess that the code has something wrong.

What am I trying to do?

For your referance, the result I want is [1,2,3,3,1,2,3,1,2,3].

my code is as follows:

```py
import time
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing

data = [1,2,3,4,10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,11,12,1,2,3,100,101]
dictionary = [1,2,3]

data_split = np.array_split(data,4)

Q = multiprocessing.Queue()

def recog_func(data):
    result = []
    for w in data:
        if w in [1,2,3]:
            result.append(w)
    print(result)
    Q.put(result)
    

procs=[]
for s in data_split:
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target = recog_func, args=(s,))
    p.start()
    result = Q.get()
    procs.extend(result)

for p in procs:
    p.join()  # 프로세스가 모두 종료될 때까지 기다린다.

end = time.time()
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The first thing I see is that the code starts and joins each process in serial. The typical way to do this is to start all of the processes then join all processes. Next, I get an `ImportError` due to a missing `time` import. Then I get `TypeError: 'Process' object is not iterable`.

Comment: @MichaelRuth  The call to `Q.get()` must precede the calls to `q.join()`. The real problem is that all the `p.start()` calls should be done before the call to  `Q.get()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two major problems. The first is that you have list `procs` into which you need to adding the `Process` instances you are creating with the following statement so that you can later call `join` on then. That is, you are missing:

```py
    procs.append(p)
```

Instead you have:

```py
    procs.extend(result)
```

This is storing the results in the `procs` list instead. So later when you attempt to execute:

```py
for p in procs:
    p.join()
```

`p` is no longer a `Process` instance but instead a `numpy.int64` instance and you will now get an `AttributeError` exception since this type of object does not have a `join` method.

The second problem is that in the following loop:

```py
for s in data_split:
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target = recog_func, args=(s,))
    p.start()
    result = Q.get()
    procs.extend(result)
```

You are starting up each process and then immediately waiting for that process to return its result via the call to `Q.get` before looping back and starting up the next process. You are therefore still not running any of these processes in parallel. Even though you have postponed calling `join`, by calling `Q.get` you have essentially waited for the first process to have completed all of its processing and written its result to the output queue before you have created and started the next process. For all intents and purposes, that first process is done processing. **You must create and start all 3 processes before you attempt to block on retrieving the results from any of the processes.** But now that all three processes are running in parallel, you really cannot be sure of the order that they complete and therefore get to write their results to the output queue. You therefore need to have three separate output queues, one for each process *if you want the results in a specific order*.

Finally, you should be aware that there is overhead in creating the processes and overhead in reading and writing to these multiprocessing queues that you would not have in a non-multiprocessing program. To justify the additional overhead, your function `recog_func` needs to be adequately CPU-intensive, which I don't believe it is. If you do timings, I believe you will find that you have not achieved greater performance.

```py
import time
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing

data = [1,2,3,4,10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,11,12,1,2,3,100,101]
dictionary = [1,2,3]

data_split = np.array_split(data,4)

def recog_func(data, q):
    result = []
    for w in data:
        if w in [1,2,3]:
            result.append(w)
    print(result)
    q.put(result)


queues = []
procs = []
results = []
for s in data_split:
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target = recog_func, args=(s, q))
    procs.append(p)
    queues.append(q)
    p.start()
for q in queues:
    result = q.get()
    results.extend(result)

for p in procs:
    p.join()  # 프로세스가 모두 종료될 때까지 기다린다.

print(results)

end = time.time()
```

Prints:

```
[1, 2, 3, 2]
[3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

> This will work fine.

```
import time
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing

data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 100, 101]
dictionary = [1, 2, 3]

data_split = np.array_split(data, 4)

Q = multiprocessing.Queue()


def recog_func(data):
    result = []
    for w in data:
        if w in [1, 2, 3]:
            result.append(w)
    print(result)
    Q.put(result)


procs = []
results = []
for s in data_split:
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=recog_func, args=(s,))
    p.start()
    results.extend(Q.get())
    procs.append(p) 

for p in procs:
    p.join()  # 프로세스가 모두 종료될 때까지 기다린다.

end = time.time()
```

Comment: See the comment posted to the question by @MichaelRuth. You are *not* running anything in parallel. See my answer.